# How to access values of a multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, key, associative-array

I have an array called `$scores` which has an index called 'team' which itself is an array with indices 'w', 'l' and 'd'. How do I access the values of 'w', 'l' and 'd'?

I have tried:

```
echo '<td>' . $scores['team']['w'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $scores['team']['l'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $scores['team']['d'] . '</td>';
```

and

```
echo '<td>' . array_values(array_keys($scores['team'], 'w')) . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . array_values(array_keys($scores['team'], 'l')) . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . array_values(array_keys($scores['team'], 'd')) . '</td>';
```

But these do not work.

declaring the array:

```
$scores = array (
                            'team' => array (
                                                'w'     => 0
                                            ,   'l'     => 0
                                            ,   'd'     => 0
                                            )
                    );
```

print_r($scores):

```
Array ( [team] => Array ( [w] => 0 [l] => 0 [d] => 0 ) [team one] => Array ( [l] => 2 [w] => 1 [d] => 1 ) [team two] => Array ( [w] => 1 [l] => 1 [d] => 1 ) [team three] => Array ( [l] => 1 ) [team four] => Array ( [w] => 1 ) [team five] => Array ( [w] => 1 ) )
```

Comment: You should provide the print_r/vardump of array.

Comment: Can you show the structure of your array ?

Comment: And you can't output the array key list in the `echo` like that anyway. It will interpolate to just `Array`. Use `implode()` additionally.

Comment: If what you say is true, then your first try should have worked. Therefore, what you say must not be true. Please show the structure of your array via `print_r($scores);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now solved - thankyou to contributors.

The problem was I was trying to access the value from within a for loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($teams); $i++)
{
    echo '<td>' . $scores[$teams[$i]]['l'] . '</td>';
}
```

This gave me the answer I was looking for.